# Linked dropdown lists?

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I would like to link 2 dropdown lists in Excel.  Searching for solutions always resulted in *cascading* dropdown lists.  What I want is two dropdown lists with the same options.  When you change one, the other changes too.

I've tried simply referencing each other but of course I get a circular reference error.  I'd love to do this without VBA if possible since I'll have a lot of them, but if it's not doable I understand.

Comment: [Which kind of DropDowns](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/02/03/3-types-of-excel-drop-down-lists-compared/) are you using?

Comment: I'm just using list validation right now.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe cannot be done without VBA, if you want both cells to be editable.

As you found out, referencing these formulas to each other creates circular references. Even if it would work, as soon as you select a value from the drop-down, any formula would be overwritten.

Hence, VBA is your only option. If the cells are on two different sheet, code for this could look like this:

In the Sheet Module of Sheet1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' monitor cell A1
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'prevent endless loop of events
    ' copy selected value to Sheet2, cell b1
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1") = Range("A1")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

In the Sheet Module of Sheet2

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' monitor cell B1 on sheet 2
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'prevent endless loop of events
    ' copy selected value to Sheet1, cell A1
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = Range("B1")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I was afraid this would be the answer.  Any suggestions for making it as dynamic as possible? I might have dozens of linked dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

As Teylyn has stated, it isn't possible in the exact way as you'd like it to work.

Another workaround besides VBA is to use form control drop-down list instead of the one in data validation:

- Go to Developer tab (if not visible then enable it according to the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx)) - Insert - form controls - "Combo box (form control)"
- insert it and resize to cover a cell
- right click on it and go "control"
- enter "input range" and "cell link"
- copy it and paste somewhere else, now, as both have the same cell link, if you change any of them, the other will be updated too.